# wordpress install config-sample.php

Tags: wordpress

I've looked for some information on this but can't seem to resolve the issue I am having. I have just installed the wordpress manually to my server and it installed fine, redirected me to the wp-admin section and I was able to login fine. But when I go to the main site it comes up with this error:

`The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try installing now.`

I typed the error in Google and came up with a few options but unfortunately none of them seemed to work.

Comment: So, you can log into your site? What files do you have in your root directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to manually install to a directory, `/wp` in that folder I have the usual wordpress files/folders plus the two files `wp-config-sample.php` and `wp-config.php` any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you log into the site?

Comment: Ok, did you try deleting the wp-config.php file?

Comment: Yeah did that, it's now letting me back into the wordpress admin but it's still coming up with that error again - update, it keeps redirecting to this page - `/wp/wp-admin/setup-config.php`

Comment: Almost sounds like Wordpress is flagged as 'doing_install'. I can check further.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm little late for this and you probably figured it out.

What happen is that you have one wordpress installed in your root folder and you want to install another wordpress in other folder or site that is inside your root/website.

All you need to do is configure both wp-config.php with their information and place both in there places again. The main one in root, and the new one in the subfolder.

Ex:
root/ (your site 1 wp-config.php file) configure it again and place it here

root/yoursite2 (your site 2 wp-config.php file) configure it again and place it here

After you have done that refresh both pages and it should work.

At least that is what was happening to me and that's what I did.

Hope I have helped you!

Cheers.

Comment: Worked for me too.Renamed the root  wp-config file, and then run the subfolder wp.Again renamed the root wp-config file to original.